# How to copy lookup item content to a basic column (single line of text, calculated,...etc)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, custom-list, copy-item

I have a list that looks up for information from other lists. 
There is a basic column (single line of text) showing quantity and an other one showing the price (lookup). 
The only thing I'd like to achieve is to be able multiplying those 2 numbers. 
SharePoint does not allow to calculate with lookup item so the easiest way does not work. 
I was trying to create a workflow but it only lets me to copy list item to an other list, but not to a given column in that list. 
Note: SPD is enabled.

Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Have you tried doing the calculation in a workflow variable?

Comment: I'm not deeply experienced in workflows. 
How would that go?

Comment: Please be more precise. Didn't understand what you meant with this sentence:  I was trying to create a workflow but it only lets me to copy list item to an other list, but not to a given column in that list. Note: SPD is enabled.? You want to make duplicated columns on same list or another list or both? Another question is do you have SPD2010 or SPD 2013?

Comment: I'm using SPD2013. 
The reason of creating the workflow is to be able calculating a single line of text item and a lookup item. 
There is a column containing the quantity (single line of text) of an item and an other column contains the price (lookup). 
As SP does not allow to calculate a single line of text with a lookup one I wanted to use a workflow to copy the content of the given lookup field to a 3rd column (e.g. single line of text) so I can use calculation. 
I hope it is more precise this way @DaniloKorac but let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your workflow, use variables to convert your fields into numbers.

```
Set variable "quantity" to "CurrentItem:Quantity (as double)"
Set variable "unitPrice" to "CurrentItem:Price (as double)" <--this is my lookup
Do calculation to multiply `quantity * unitPrice` and set your total Price field.
```